# HAProxy not keeping HTTP connection open

Tags: node.js, http, haproxy, server-sent-events

I have a Node.js server that uses Server-Sent Events (SSE) to allow push notifications to connected web clients.  It works beautifully when the browser talks to Node directly.

However, when I place haproxy in the middle, as it must be for production to meet other requirements, the connections are closed and reopened (thanks to SSE's auto-reconnect) every 30 seconds.  I've changed and tried everything I know of and can find online in the haproxy configuration.

Most info out there and in their documentation examples deal with sockets, but there is very little about SSE support.  Should it support persistent HTTP connections for SSE?  If so, what is the trick in to configure it?

My config follows:
    global
        daemon
        # maximum number of concurrent connections
        maxconn 4096
        # drop privileges after port binding
        user nobody
        group nogroup
        # store pid of process in the file
        pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
        # create this socket for stats
        stats socket /var/run/socket-haproxy

```
defaults
    log global
    mode http

    # disable logging of null connections
    option dontlognull

    # I've tried all these to no avail
    #option http-server-close
    #option httpclose
    option http-keep-alive

    # Add x-forwarded-for header to forward clients IP to app
    option forwardfor

    # maximum time to wait for a server connection to succeed. Can be as low as few msec if Haproxy and server are on same LAN.
    timeout connect 1s
    # maximum inactivity time on client side. Recommended to keep it same as server timeout.
    timeout client 24d
    # maximum time given to server to respond to a request
    timeout server 24d
    # Long timeout for WebSocket connections.
    timeout tunnel 8h

    # timeout for keep alive
    timeout http-keep-alive 60s
    # maximum time to wait for client to send full request. Keep it like 5s for get DoS protection.
    timeout http-request 5s

    # enable stats web interface. very helpful to see what's happening in haproxy
    stats enable
    # default refresh time for web interface
    stats refresh 30s

# this frontend interface receives the incoming http requests and forwards to https then handles all SSL requests
frontend public
    # HTTP
    bind :80

    # by default, all incoming requests are sent to Node.js
    default_backend node_backend

    # redirect to the SSE backend if /ionmed/events (eventum #????)
    acl req_sse_path path_beg /ionmed/events
    use_backend node_sse_backend if req_sse_path

    # redirect to the tomcat backend if Time Clock, ViewerJS, Spell Checker, Tomcat Manager, or eScripts (eventum #1039, #1082)
    acl req_timeclock_path path_beg /TimeClock/
    acl req_manager_path path_beg /manager/
    acl req_spelling_path path_beg /jspellEvolution/
    acl req_escripts_path path_beg /ionmed/escripts
    use_backend tomcat_backend if req_timeclock_path or req_manager_path or req_spelling_path or req_escripts_path

    # for displaying HAProxy statistics
    acl req_stats path_beg /stats
    use_backend stats if req_stats

# node backend, transfer to port 8081
backend node_backend
    # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
    # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    server node_server localhost:8081

# node SSE backend, transfer to port 8082
backend node_sse_backend
    # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
    # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    server node_sse_server localhost:8082

# tomcat backend, transfer to port 8888
backend tomcat_backend
    # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
    # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    server tomcat_server localhost:8888
```

Comment: Okay, I have it working but probably not the "best" way.  Turns out, I did not need to change my haproxy.cfg at all.  So the timeouts are set back to the defaults.  But for some reason, haproxy requires my app to send heartbeats to any connected SSE client at an interval < 30 seconds.  So I'm sending them at 25 seconds and all is good.  If I don't send them or make the interval 30 or more, I get the disconnect/ reconnect cycles.

Comment: A bit more info:  The auto-reconnects for SSE does not work when going through HAProxy.  If I bypass it and access the Node.js server directly from the client, then the connection will continue to retry to reconnect when I bring the server down, and once it is back up, the connection is ready again with no user intervention.  When using HAProxy, once the Node.js server is down, the client gives up after one reconnect attempt and closes the connection.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working properly, I am working on getting this same setup going and am having issues even getting the data from server to client with HAProxy in between.  Sidenote the SSE reconnect interval you experienced is set by the client and is part of the SSE protocol, not anything to do with HAProxy.